# How to use Fourier Transform with non-trivial boundary conditions such as in potential flow around a plate?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, closed-form, potential-theory

I'd specifically like to be able to solve this PDE with boundary conditions corresponding to flow around a line (plate cross-section), otherwise known as flow-tangency, with integral transforms.

$$(1) \quad {{\partial^2 \psi} \over {\partial x^2}}+{{\partial^2 \psi} \over {\partial y^2}}=0$$
Where the boundary condition satisfies that the streamline is constant at the boundary of this line.
$$(2) \quad \psi(x,0)=\mu \ , \quad |x| \lt r$$

Fourier Transform (1) with respect to x, and simplify using the derivative rules. We get.

$$(3) \quad {{d^2 \Psi} \over {d y^2}}-\omega^2 \cdot \Psi=0$$
Solve (3) up to additive constants to get...
$$(4) \quad \Psi=A \cdot e^{-|\omega| \cdot y}+B \cdot e^{|\omega| \cdot y}$$

I've taken the absolute value because I feel as though the square root of something squared should be positive. However, this could very well be the problem with my derivation. Feedback would be welcome. I could derive the rest of my wrong result, but at this point I think the error in my reasoning has become clear enough. How do I fix it?

If it helps, I eliminate the right side of (4) to avoid an infinite potential, apply an IFT, then apply the convolution theorem and end up with...
$$\psi(x,y)={1 \over \pi} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x,0) \cdot {y \over {(x-\omega)^2+y^2}} \ d\omega$$

**My Thoughts:** I think that perhaps the boundary conditions need to be expanded to enforce a constant velocity as the distance tends to infinity. I'm also pretty sure that putting absolute values on the solution to the ODE was a mistake. Edit: It seems as though the problem I solve is correct, but isn't the problem I wanted to solve. Perhaps someone could show me where my boundary conditions went wrong?

**Questions:** I'd like some help deriving flow around a plate cross-section using **Integral Transforms**. I'm not interested in using other methods that don't involve a Fourier Transform or at least an integral transform of one kind or another. Basically the point is to use integral transforms not separation by variables or some other technique. Below is what I am trying to describe, I've just flipped the axis in the above "derivation"...

Also, how does one generally use an integral transform if the boundary conditions involve 0 around a body and a constant at infinity or other region? For instance, how do you solve the particle in a box problem if $\Psi$ must be 0 beyond the boundary's of the box? As another question, how do you use the Fourier transform in polar coordinates? Is it legal to change the 0 to $2\pi$ angular region to an infinite bound? How about changing the semi-infinite region to an infinite region? For instance, flow around a cylinder would combine 0 valued boundary conditions, and all the above problems.

I'm having a hard time asking this question, but I've tried my best. I'll summarize. How do you use the Fourier transform for boundary conditions and coordinate systems similar to the above, such as flow tangency?

[image]

Comment: I think these might be of some interest to you: http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/apm346h1/20129/L19.html https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=solve%20laplace%20equation%20fourier%20transform

Comment: Concerning the solution you got at the beginning, it is the convolution with the Poisson kernel. How to use Fourier transform to solve PDE? you could read about pseudo-differential equations, the books of Hörmander are a good source. For example, Calderón used harmonic analysis techniques to solve the problem you posed at the beginning with Lipschitz boundary. In fact, the Chicago school of analysis promoted harmonic analysis as a tool to solve PDE. See the work of Kenig, Ponce and Venga. I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: @user39490 I'm not asking how to solve pde's with Fourier transforms. I'm asking how to incorporate non-trivial boundary conditions into the method.

Answer (score 2):

Trying this a little differently, using Laplace Transforms (since I'm used to those).  I'm using the graph's coordinate system, so this is in terms of y, not x (since the graph helps).

$$\mathcal L(\psi(x,y)) = \Psi(y,s) $$

$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dy^2} + s^2\Psi = 0$$

$$ \Psi(y,s) = C_1(s)\sin(sy) + C_2(s)\cos(sy) $$

We know immediately that, in terms of y, $\Psi(-y,s) = \Psi(y,s)$, so that means $C_1(s) = 0$  This solves the "absolute value" problem from earlier.

This leaves the boundary conditions: $\lim_{y \to \infty} \psi(x,y) = 0$, which requires a negative exponential in $C_2(s)$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \psi(x,y) = 0$  Now the tricky boundary condition of when x = 0, for some |y| < r, the function goes to a constant.  This is best handled with the derivative, not a constant:

$$\frac{d\psi(x,y<a)}{dx} = 0 $$

Which means breaking up the discontinuity into different plates.  In fact, I'd use four plates, as I've shown here:

[image: Four Plates]

This then turns into a system of partial differential equations, each one of the functions convoluting the output.  Ultimately, it's a tricky problem and that's when FEA usually gets involved.

Comment: Seeing as how you don't derive a final result, I can't really award the bounty to this...however good work on the first part :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have time for the final answer.  Figured I'd start here, see if that helped you, and if you can try and give me some specifics on your input signal I can try and derive to the final answer.  But it gets complicated - all the convolutions of the signals on each other lead to a blur.

Comment: This isn't actually applied so I don't really have any initial data, besides a flow tangency, which just means all fluid velocity perpendicular at the plate's surface is 0 and the flow parallel to the plate is constant. And that the line integral around the plate with respect to potential is 0. Don't know if that last statement is 100% correct or needed though.